# Why can't Java find a file inside of the main source folder?

Tags: java

I'm working on a game, and Java can't seem to find my file.

My play sound function is :

```
 void playSound(String soundLocation) {
    
    try
    {
        File soundPath = new File(soundLocation);
        
        if (soundPath.exists()) {
            AudioInputStream audioInput = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundPath);
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.start();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Press OK to stop playing");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Can't find file");
        }
    }
    
    catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    
  }
```

In my main class I have :

```
 package game;

 public class GUI_Handler {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    String soundPath = "c://users/harry/java workspace/SlavaSourcecode/src/game/jump.wav";
    
    SOUND_Handler soundStuff = new SOUND_Handler();
    soundStuff.playSound(soundPath);
  }

}
```

It outputs " Can't find file");

Please help! Thanks,
Harry

Comment: What package is the first file in?

Comment: Are you sure it should read `c://` with two slashes? May or may not matter.

Answer (score 1):

You must replace all `/` with `\` but in Java you must also escape the backslash with another backslash to prevent it being treated as a special character.

So, once you've replaced the `/`s with `\` you then need to replace all `\` with `\\`:

If you take what you already have you can amend `soundPath` to:

```java
soundPath.replace("//","\").replace("\","\\");
```

And it should work.

Or you can manually edit the path to:

```java
"c:\\users\\harry\\java workspace\\SlavaSourcecode\\src\\game\\jump.wav"
```

Note though that this is not at all portable to other machines. In reality what would be better is if you used a build tool (Gradle/Maven) which has a standard file structure (a "convention" used by most developers these days). The file structure has two directories: one for source code `src/main/java`, and another for resources `src/main/resources`. Typically you'd stick any such assets in the `resources` directory and load the `jump.wav` from the resources dir which is always accessible relatively on the classpath.